# How would I search for a phrase in a section of text in HTML and then highlight/color it?

Tags: html, css, replace

I've seen a lot of similar questions but I can't seem to figure out exactly how to go about it in my situation. Essentially, I have three different variables: article, arg1, arg2. Article is a string that is about 5 sentences long. Arg1 and arg2 is a sentence/phrase in the article. I'm going to have the article as a basic < p > tag on the website. But I want arg1 and arg2 within the article to be a different color or highlighted or something, so it's obvious where in the article it is. How would I go about searching through the text in the < p > tag, finding each argument, and then changing the style of specific text?

Comment: Html and css are not programming languages and this question seems to require programming, given the variables and args. Are you using javascript? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve - you want sentences that match variables to be highlighted?  If you want this to be static (not using js), you can just create a new <p> tag and give it a class and then in your css, style the background color accordingly.  It seems like a header tag would show where articles are, but again its unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry yes, I would be using javascript as well @Hunter Wiley. I am pushing a lot of data onto the website and each sample has the article and those two arguments. I can easily switch through the batch and update the article, but I want the args colored in within the article each time I switch into a new article.

Comment: You can use [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) for this if you dont want to build your own. It does exactly what you are asking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace with regex is useful:

```js
let str = document.getElementById("str");
let result;
result = str.innerHTML.replace(/Lorem Ipsum/gi, `<span class="my-span">Lorem Ipsum</span>`).replace(/specimen book/gi, `<span class="my-span">specimen book</span>`);
str.innerHTML = result;
console.log(str);
```

```css
p .my-span {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<p id="str">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and specimen book typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, Lorem Ipsum but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,Lorem Ipsum and more recently with desktop specimen book publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't be hard to achieve by splitting the paragraph into chunks and iterate through occurrences of the variables to add `<mark></mark>` tag around them.

this can be improved but a simple example would be something like:

```js
let arg = "dummy";
let paragraph = document.getElementById('paragraph');

let broken = paragraph.innerHTML.split(arg);

paragraph.innerHTML = '';

broken.map((part, i) => {
  paragraph.innerHTML += i + 1 >= broken.length ? part : part + ' <mark>' + arg + '</mark>';
});
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">this is just a dummy text and like any other dummy text it does nothing besides being dummy</p>
```

**Edit**

Emy's solution is more elegant indeed :)